# CSS - white-space: nowrap overrides width of container element in responsive site

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm playing around with making a responsive site. I have a page that displays a list of divs use flex layout. Each div will contain a title and description for a list of recipes. I want the description to display on one line, no wrap. I currently have this working using:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipses;
white-space: nowrap;
```

However, I noticed a strange result when the screen width gets to a small enough size. The div with the text no longer shrinks in size as the screen gets smaller and is set a certain width that makes it overlap with the parent div. When I remove the white-space: nowrap property, the divs are responsive as the screen size changes, but the intended result is to have the text not wrap.

See gif for demonstration

```
HTML
<div class="wrapper">
  <main>
    <div class="recipe-main">
      <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content">
          <p id="title">Title</p>
          <p id="desc">Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p id="title">Title</p>
          <p id="desc">Description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

CSS
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.recipe-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.content-container {
  flex: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

p {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: See gif for demonstration you say?

Comment: The source by itself doesn't really demonstrate anything; see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/w72c4eb5/).

Comment: Think there was a problem with overflow and flex, don't think they ever solved it, or only in some cases, some browsers.